# Importing multiple XML tables in Excel, usinv Macro VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba, import

I am developing a macro VBA for importing tables present in .xml files, stored on the same folder of the excel file. I want to import each table on its own sheet (in ITalian is called "Foglio").

Below I report the code. I get an error, it looks like filename or path are not properly defined.

```
Sub Vai()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim fso As Object
Dim folder As Object
Dim file As Object
Dim percorso As String
Dim nome As String
Dim n As Integer



n = 2

Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.Filesystemobject")
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path)
For Each file In folder.Files
        percorso = file.Path
        Sheets.Add.Name = "Foglio" & n
        
''The following part was made wit macro recorder and I made some modifications on the resulting code. I think the problem is here.
     
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Letture_canali", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Origine = Xml.Tables(File.Contents("" & percorso & ""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Table0 = Origine{0}[Table]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Modificato tipo"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table0,{{""index"", Int64.Type}, {""ch1"", Int64.Type}, {""ch2"", Int64.Type}, {""ch3"", Int64.Type}, {""ch4"", Int64.Type}, {""encoder1"", Int64.Type}, {""encoder2"", Int64.Type}, {""te" & _
        "mpo"", Int64.Type}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Modificato tipo"""
    
    With Worksheets("Foglio" & n).ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Letture_canali;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Letture_canali]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Letture_canali"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
        

        n = n + 1
       
    
    Next



End Sub
```

Does somebody know where the problem can be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Letture_canali", Formula:= _
        "let " & vbCrLf & "    Origine = Xml.Tables(File.Contents(""" & percorso & """))," & vbCrLf & _
        "    Table0 = Origine{0}[Table]," & vbCrLf & _
        "    #""Modificato tipo"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table0,{{""index"", Int64.Type}," & _
        " {""ch1"", Int64.Type}, {""ch2"", Int64.Type}, {""ch3"", Int64.Type}, {""ch4"", Int64.Type}, " & _
        " {""encoder1"", Int64.Type}, {""encoder2"", Int64.Type}, {""tempo"", Int64.Type}})" & vbCrLf _
        & "in" & vbCrLf & "    #""Modificato tipo"""
```

Comment: It fixed up 80% of my problems, I added a modification at the end `.ListObject.DisplayName = "Letture_canali" & n`. Can I ask you how did you get this code?? Now I have only an error when it try to load a new file and it is not exsisting.

Comment: I got that by editing your code.  You were missing two double-quotes here  `... Xml.Tables(File.Contents("" & percorso & "")) ...`  I'm not sure how you  might get errors with non-existent files though?  Aren't you looping over the files in the folder - they should all exist...

Comment: I put two double quotes you added a third one? `... Xml.Tables(File.Contents(""" & percorso & """)) ...`? The other problem fixed. It was trying to open also the excel file. I added: `If UCase(file.Name) Like "*.XML" Then`

Comment: Yes that's all I did apart from using the constant `vbCrLf` in place of `Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10)`   Good to hear you got it working.

Comment: Of course! Now I discovered a new one!! It is importing with dot as decimal separator and not comma ...

Comment: Anyhow ... I fixed this also! By re-recording the macro, replacing in PowerQuert dot `.` with comma `,` Thank you for your support!